# How to wait for an element before clicking on the button

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I have a 3 dots button which I click on to configure an element on a grid. If I step through it step through it nicely. When I debug my script it doesn't see the 3 dot configure button on the grid. It is as it goes too quick.

```
[Then(@ "user clicks on the configure for client buttons for main flow")] 
public void ThenUserClicksOnTheConfigureForClientButtonsForMainFlow() 
{
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
  IWebElement waitDots = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.CssSelector("#grid > div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > a"))));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#grid > div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > a > i"))).Build().Perform();
  IWebElement ConfigureDots = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#grid > div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > a > i"));
  ConfigureDots.Click();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message and stack trace, as well as a representative amount of HTML that you are attempting to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to insert a Thread.Sleep(), usually 1 to a few seconds will do. The "correct" way is to call WebDriverWait() as you have done, except you've probably specified the wrong condition, and it can be quite difficult to find a WebDriverWait() condition that actually works.

BTW, the code you're showing us doesn't look like it starts at the beginning of your test. Just a warning, sometimes your wait needs to come earlier than you think, like in the code that runs before this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Thread.Sleep() and it seems be not working as it still tells me cannot find the button on the grid. I have used Thread.Sleep(5) and debug through and it doesn't look like it is waiting 5 secs, it just past through quickly.